# Unity Player Controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with applying velocity to my character controller and using Vector3.normalize to make diagonal movement the same speed as forward movement. When I use Vector3.normilize it normalizes x, y, and z. I need it to only normalize x, and z so that I can increase y more than 1 or -1, making so that I can make gravity pull you down faster the longer you are falling, eventually reaching terminal velocity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3();

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float velocity;
    public float terminalVelocity;
    CharacterController characterController;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (characterController == null)
        {
            characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), moveDirection.y, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        // moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized;
        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            if (moveDirection.y > -terminalVelocity)
            {
                moveDirection.y -= Time.deltaTime * velocity;
            }
        } else
        {
            moveDirection.y = -2;
        }
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

When I run this code the gravity works, but the diagonal movement doesn't. When I run the code with the commented out moveDirection.normalize diagonal movement works, but the gravity doesn't. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use a `Vector2`, for the input values. Normalize that and copy those values into `moveDirection` leaving `y` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the line of code, at the end of the `Update()` function:

```
characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
```

with:

```
characterController.Move((new Vector3(moveDirection.x, 0, moveDirection.z).normalized + Vector3.up * moveDirection.y) * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
```